# Unity script fields - unique to each instance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a message system for my Unity game. I have this script, `TouchPlayer` attached to objects which the player can interact with. I can then just edit the `MyTextArea` field in the editor for each object instance.

It's not performing exactly as I expect it should. For example:

If I have 2 objects with this script, I can trigger the collision with one, press X, and the message displays. I leave the collision zone, go to the other object, and the other object's message already displays (without the prompt, `PRESS X`). Why is this?

```cs
public class TouchPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    [TextArea] public string MyTextArea;
    [SerializeField] GameObject Player;
    [SerializeField] GameObject UIMessageBoxGroup;
    [SerializeField] GameObject MessageBox;
    public TMP_Text messageTextBox;

    bool showMessage = false;
    bool collided = false;

    void Start() {
      UIMessageBoxGroup.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update() {
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)) {
        showMessage = true;
      }

      if (collided) {
        if (showMessage) {
          messageTextBox.text = MyTextArea;
        } else {
          messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";
        }
      }

      transform.LookAt(Player.transform.position);
      transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
      if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        collided = true;
        UIMessageBoxGroup.SetActive(true);
      }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
      if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
        collided = false;
        showMessage = false;
        UIMessageBoxGroup.SetActive(false);
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you dragged in the respective `messageTextBox` in each of the instance fields? maybe you dragged in the same by mistake

Comment: Just to check: you're talking about attributes such as `[TextArea]` and `[SerializeField]`, right?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay - it's the same `messageTextBox`, seems to me that's not my issue here though? @Llama, yes, also those like `collided` and `showMessage`

Comment: `collided` and `showMessage` are [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)

Comment: I think I am not understanding. if its the same `messageTextBox` to have the previously set text value would be the expected outcome. if Its the same you should then handle the state in the `OnTriggerExit` and set the text to the collided = false state with `messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";`

Comment: @rustyBucketBay, the part in Update() which checks the value of `collided` and `showMessage` -- if I understand correctly this shouldn't be influenced by the other object's field values / previously displayed message, right?

Comment: @Llama thank you for the info. I'll do some more reading on that.

Comment: " if I understand correctly this shouldn't be influenced by the other object's field values / previously displayed message, right?" if the `public TMP_Text messageTextBox;` references the **same** `TMP_Text` instance, it will

Comment: thats what I mean with dragging in the respective `TMP_Text`s to the respective `TouchPlayer`s, because if its the same you need to reset the state, and if its not, you need to check in the inspector that you dragged the corrected ones in case they might be the same. Hope I am making myself understood :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay, I really don't understand this. Doesn't `showMessage` get set to false when leaving the previous object's collider? So it should display `PRESS X` when I enter the new object's collider? From running my code it seems you're correct but I can't understand the logic

Comment: @rustyBucketBay ah okay, so does that mean I need a new `TMP_Text` object for every single NPC I can talk to?

Comment: would not need that expressly, but you need to have you logic set according to how is it going to work :). Find below an answer with what I think is your problem if you are operating with the same one `messageTextBox` object in all the `TouchPlayer` instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on each instances in `Update` you do

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)) 
{ 
    showMessage = true; 
}
```

this is done for all the instances simultaneously! ;)

=> Even for all instances where you never did collide with the `showMessage` stays `true` forever. So as soon as you collide with one of these you immediately handle the `if(showMessage)` case.

You would want to make sure input isn't even handled at all as long as you didn't collide yet:

```
void Update() 
{
    // If not collided do absolutely nothing
    if(!collided) return;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)) 
    {
        showMessage = true;
    }

    messageTextBox.text = showMessage? MyTextArea : "PRESS X";

    transform.LookAt(Player.transform.position);
    transform.Rotate(0, -90, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ohhh yeah!! Thank you @derHugo, it's so obvious now :D

Answer (score 1):

I think the the problem is you are setting `collided = false;` in the ontrigger exit.

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
  if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
    collided = false;
    showMessage = false;
    UIMessageBoxGroup.SetActive(false);
  }
}
```

So the `messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";` will never be reached, so you are not achieving the default state you are after.

```
if (collided) { //this will be false
    if (showMessage) {
      messageTextBox.text = MyTextArea;
    } else {
      messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";
    }
  }
```

So you need to reset the state in the `OntriggerExit` :

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
  if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
    collided = false;
    showMessage = false;
    UIMessageBoxGroup.SetActive(false);
    messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X"; //set the default state
  }
}
```

**Or** incorporate the collided condition to your update, so that the state is updated when collided is false:

```
if (showMessage && collided) {
  messageTextBox.text = MyTextArea;
} else {
  messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately I can't get either solution to work. Also, "So the `messageTextBox.text = "PRESS X";` will never be reached, so you are not achieving the default state you are after." -- would this not be reachable when the player collides with the second object's collider trigger?

Comment: you're right on that. Regarding "I leave the collision zone, go to the other object, and the other object's message already displays (without the prompt, PRESS X). Why is this?" you mean that even when you press X the text does not change? Because it makes sense that the previous message is shown until you press x...

Comment: I've solved it! If I add `showMessage = false;` to `OnTriggerEnter()`, it works. I've tested with multiple NPCs just now. I have no idea why it wouldn't already be false when it's initialised, or when exiting from a previous NPC (which shouldn't affect the new NPC anyway...), but it's working. Thank you for your help! I'll add a post to "Answer" the question

Comment: ok, that does not make much sense to me, because `showMessage` is false by default...but nevermind. If you put it to work you might realize later on where is it being set to true...

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make sense to me either. The code I originally posted is the entire class, I can't see where it would become true. Very strange

Answer (score 0):

**If I add `showMessage = false;` to `OnTriggerEnter()`, it works.**

*I assumed it would already be false when the variable is initialised (`bool showMessage = false;`), but apparently not...?*